# Is parameterisation needed in this instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, uwp

Im designing a UWP app that uses an SQLite database to store its information. From previous research I have blearnt that using the SQLite function `SQLiteConnection.Update()` and `SQLiteConnetion.Insert()` functions are safe to use as the inputs are sanitised before entering in the database.

The next step I need to do is sync that data with an online database - in this case SQL Server - using a service layer as my go between. Given that the data was previously sanitised by the SQLite database insert, do I still need to parameterise the object values using the service layer before they are passed to my SQL Server database?

The simple assumption says yes because, despite them being sanitised by the SQLite input, they are technically still raw strings that could have an effect on the main database if not parameterised when sending them there.

Should I just simply employ the idea of "If in doubt, parameterise" ?

Comment: In one word: yes. Or even better: not only if you're in doubt but *always*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you should always use SQL parameters. There are a few reasons why you should do so:

- Security.
- Performance. If you use parameters the reuse of execution plans could increase. For details see this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580(v=sql.105).aspx).
- Reliability. It is always easier to make a mistake if you build SQL commands by concatenating strings.

Comment: +Avoiding conversion errors. The alternative is usually to forcefully convert everything into a string and to then force the database engine to convert everything back into natural data types.